# IndexError: list index out of range graph diameter

Tags: python, graph, indexing, range

this is my code:

```
class Graph(object):

def __init__(self, graph_dict={}):
    self.__graph_dict = graph_dict

def vertices(self):
    return list(self.__graph_dict.keys())


def find_all_paths(self, start_vertex, end_vertex, path=[]):
    graph = self.__graph_dict
    path = path + [start_vertex]
    if start_vertex == end_vertex:
        return [path]
    if start_vertex not in graph:
        return []
    paths = []
    for vertex in graph[start_vertex]:
        if vertex not in path:
            extended_paths = self.find_all_paths(vertex, 
                                             end_vertex, 
                                             path)
            for p in extended_paths:
                paths.append(p)


    return paths

def diameter(self):


    v = self.vertices() 
    pairs = [ (v[i],v[j]) for i in range(len(v)) for j in range(i+1, len(v)-1)]
    smallest_paths = []
    for (s,e) in pairs:
        paths = self.find_all_paths(s,e)
        smallest = sorted(paths, key=len)[0]
        smallest_paths.append(smallest)

    smallest_paths.sort(key=len)


    diameter = len(smallest_paths[-1])
    return diameter
```

When I run the comand:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

from collections import defaultdict
g = defaultdict(list)
with open("/Volumes/City_University/data_mining/Ecoli.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        key, val = line.split()
        g[key].append(val)
for k, v in g.items():
    print(k, v)

    graph = Graph(g)

print("Vertices of graph:")
print(graph.vertices())
print(graph.find_all_paths("0", "3"))

print(graph.diameter())
```

I get this error:
File "", line 70, in 
    print(graph.diameter())

File "", line 40, in diameter
    smallest = sorted(paths, key=len)[0]

IndexError: list index out of range

The graph is a very big one. It has 3633 edges.
Any reason why I get this error?
Is there another function I can use to calcute the diameter of this graph?